# ¿Cómo añadir un menu en la ActionBar de PreferenceActivity en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Cómo se puede agregar un menú en la actionbar de la `PreferenceActivity`?

El código es el que genera el android studio

```
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Has probado a utilizar las [PrefrenceFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) ?

Puedes hacer que tu `Activity` extienda de `AppCompatActivy` y gestionar tu `ActionBar` y el menú de forma normal y poner las preferencias en el `PreferenceFragment`

Comment: llevo toda la mañana dando vueltas, con lo fácil que era

Comment: Me alegra saber que te ha servido!!! Yo hace tiempo también estuve dándole muchas vueltas hasta que encontré esta forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 2):

Pequeño ejemplo de como añadir un menú a la actionbar.

XML del menú

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.webserveis.app.abouttemplate.AboutActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_clear_pref"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/clear_preferences"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Añadir eso a `onCreate` de la `SettingsActivity` que extiende de `AppCompatPreferenceActivity`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);
    return true;
}
```

En el `onMenuItemSelected` procesar la acción del menú.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch(id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.action_clear_pref:
            Log.d(TAG, "Clear Preferences: ");
            clearAllPreferences();
            restartActivity();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muy buen aporte, nunca había agregado un menú al PreferenceActivity, veo que es similar a como se agrega a una Activity.